# Daemonizing Multithreaded Server

Tags: c++, c, multithreading

I am writing a multithreaded web server which has to run in daemon mode.I have written the code but the program gets crashed when run in daemon mode. If I don't include the code for daemonizing the server, the program is running fine. Can anybody tell me where I am going wrong?

```
pid_t pid,cid;
pid = fork();
if(pid<0)
{
exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
 }
if(pid>0)
{
    exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
 }
umask(0);
cid=setsid();
std::cout<<"Process id after:"<<pid<<std::endl;
std::cout<<"Session id:"<<cid<<std::endl;
close(STDIN_FILENO);
close(STDOUT_FILENO);
close(STDERR_FILENO);

pthread_t t1,t2;
pthread_t threads[threadnum];
pthread_attr_t attr;
if ((s = socket(AF_INET, soctype, 0)) < 0) {
    perror("socket");
    exit(1);
}
pthread_attr_init(&attr);
pthread_create(&t1,NULL,setup_server,NULL);  // thread for accepting the requests
pthread_create(&t2,NULL,scheduler,NULL);     // thread for scheduling the requests
```

Comment: unrelated: it doesn't look like a [standard Unix daemon](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3143/#correct-daemon-behaviour)

Comment: This is a deamonizing in a c++ program...

Comment: the rules are the same whatever the language

Comment: "the program gets crashed" - details?

Comment: Have you tried running it in a debugger? Where in your program does the crash happen?

Answer (score 0):

What is the purpose of the following lines of code:

```
if(pid>0)
{
    exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
}
```

If you need the child process to exit instantly, then do not fork your program at all.

Also, please post the functions setup_server() and scheduler() in order to help you with your program.